# ImmutableJS Records won't detect interface with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I'm trying to get running Typescript with Immutable 3.8.1.

```
import { Record } from "immutable";

class Person extends Record({
    name: "viktor" as string,
}) {
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

const person = new Person({ name: "petko" });

console.log(person.getName());
```

this code produces the following error:

```
    Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Person'.
     5 | }) {
     6 |    getName() {
  >  7 |        return this.name;
       |                    ^^^^
     8 |    }
     9 | }
```

but it does compile and run. However, when I try to add `name: string;` just over the getName declaration (in the class body), the error goes away, but `getName()` returns undefined every time. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "*produces the following error but it does compile and run*" - how does that fit together?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that advanced in TS, but if I got it right, the problem is that although the property `name` **does** exist on type `Person`, the TypeScript compiler doesn't know about it, because it's created dynamically at runtime.

So, you have two ways:

- Use the immutable record's `get` function to read the value:

  ```
    import { Record } from "immutable";

    class Person extends Record({
        name: "viktor" as string,
    }) {
        getName() {
            return this.get("name");
        }
    }

    const person = new Person({ name: "petko" });

    console.log(person.getName());
  ```
- Cast to `any`:

  ```
    import { Record } from "immutable";

    class Person extends Record({
        name: "viktor" as string,
    }) {
        getName() {
            return (<any> this).name;
        }
    }

    const person = new Person({ name: "petko" });

    console.log(person.getName());
  ```